# Facebook Graph Api v2.10 workarounds for feeds with titles or shares with large thumbnails

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb.ui

I want let user share image from my website. I want it to be bigger thumbnail using fb.ui share option, code bellow works but it reduces my large image to smaller.

Code for sharing:

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'share_open_graph',
        action_type: 'og.shares',
        action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            object : {
              // 'og:url': 'url', // your url to share
               'og:title': 'Here my custom title',
               'og:description': 'here custom description',
               'og:image': 'image_url'

            }
        })
        })
```

result of code above:
[image: result]

I am able to post image with prefered size by using feed option, code and result is bellow. But problem is I can not add additional information like title or message.

```
 FB.ui({
         method: 'feed',
    name: 'name',
    picture: 'image_url',
    caption: 'caption',
    description: 'description',
    message: 'message'
    });
```

[image]

I know message, title and description are deprecated for feed option, and big thumbnails are not working for now for share option. If anyone have some solution for this, or knows some workaround let me know.

So I need solution for getting bigger thumbnail in post,size as image is....or posting some additional information with feed image.

Comment: use images with correct sizes in the og tags of your shared url. see facebook docs about the correct sizes, there is a lot of info about that.

Comment: for older Graph Api versions, recomended size was  600 x 315 and bigger to get large thumbnail, but now it is not working at all, I am using 1200x1200 just for case. If tou have some useful link, please provide it.

Comment: why 1200x1200? that´s completely wrong, the aspect ratio is very important. here´s the link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices/#images

Comment: I tried recomended sizes, still not working.

Comment: how exactly did you try? please be more specific. did you add the correct og tags with the correct image in your shared url? did you refresh the tags with the debugger? what is the exact url you want to share?

Comment: FB.ui({
            method: 'share_open_graph',
            action_type: 'og.shares',
            action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                object : {
                   'og:title': 'Here my custom title',
                   'og:description': 'here custom description',
                   'og:image': 'https://dummyimage.com/1200x630/7a587a/fff',
                    'og:image:width': '1200' ,
                    'og:image:height': '630'

                }
            })
            });


This is my new code. Same result, small thumbnail.

Comment: i told you specifically to add the open graph tags in the shared url directly (<meta ...)

Comment: I actual don't know how to achieve that. I am using this javascript code to share post from my single page app. If you have some exapmle with metadata with prefered size, please provide it.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters

Comment: How to invoke these tags with javascript? Where to put them, in head tag?

Comment: yes, in the head tag, where you normally put metatags. you should really learn the very basics of html, no offense ;)

Comment: you do not need to "invoke" the tags, facebook automatically gets them directly from the shared url.

Comment: As you can see from code from above, I am not using og:url, just sending image and description. I will try now to make with url

Comment: Still not working, same size.

Comment: please share the url, so we can test it

Comment: I am curently working from localhost and I am using some dummy images in the code that you can see above. As I was searching I saw lot of comments that says that Graph Api v2.10 is making all thumbnails small. And actually my question was is there some workaround. Because as I see, lot of people have this problem lately. If you have some other idea how can share, that is different from code above, please provide a link.

Comment: localhost does not work for og tags, facebook needs to be able to access your url